# Change attribute of a specific element using linq

Tags: c#, linq

i want to change value of a specific element and attribute.

but i'm receiving an error:

```
cannot convert from 'System.Xml.Linq.XNamespace' to 'System.Xml.Linq.XName'
```

and the part where the ide pointing the error is the abc

```
where (string)el.Attribute(abc) == ab
```

and this is the input xml

```
<p>
    <math xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                    <mi>n</mi>
                    <mo>!</mo>
                  </math>
    <MoreTag><math xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                    <mi>n</mi>
                    <mo>!</mo>
                  </math></MoreTag>
</p>
```

and this is my code

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("myxml.xml");
            XNamespace ab = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
            XNamespace abc = "xmlns:xlink";
            IEnumerable<XElement> equationFormat =
                from el in doc.Descendants("math").ToList()
                where (string)el.Attribute(abc) == ab
                select el;
            foreach (XElement el in equationFormat)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(el);
            }
```

im changing this:

```
<math xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

to this:

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" alttext="" >
```

but i can't do it because of the error. i already search for the solution. but the problem is still the same

and i followed the tutorial from msdn. what did i missed?

```
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693115.aspx
```

Comment: I think your code is incomplete. I don’t see where you are trying to change anything.

Comment: the code is not complete yet sir. because on the LINQ part im having an error

Comment: But where is the code producing the error?

Comment: The `XElement.Attribute()` method expects an `XName` parameter and not an `XNamespace`. Does it work if you change the `XNamespace` declarations to `XName`?

Comment: no sir because if i change it to Xname. im also having an error: Additional information: The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.

Answer (score 1):

`xlink` there is part of a namespace declaration.  The name of the attribute is the same as if it was a name in the `XNamespace.Xmlns` namespace.  You can change the declaration by searching for the attributes to change and replace the value to your new namespace.  Be warned that you *will* have to rename any nodes or attributes that are in that namespace as well (which your example does not show).

```
var xmlns = XNamespace.Xmlns;
XNamespace oldNs = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
XNamespace newNs = "http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML";

// change the declarations
var decls =
    from a in doc.Descendants().Attributes()
    where a.Name == xmlns + "xlink"
    select a;
foreach (var decl in decls)
    decl.Value = newNs.NamespaceName;

// change the names of existing elements
var nodes =
    from n in doc.Descendants()
    where n.Name.Namespace == oldNs
    select n;
foreach (var node in nodes)
    node.Name = newNs + node.Name.LocalName;

// don't forget the attributes as well
var attrs =
    from a in doc.Descendants().Attributes()
    where a.Name.Namespace == oldNs
    select a;
foreach (var attr in attrs.ToList())
{
    // can't change the names directly, the attributes must be replaced
    var newName = newNs + attr.Name.LocalName;
    attr.Parent.SetAttributeValue(newName, attr.Value);
    attr.Remove();
}
```

Comment: sir thank you for your time. but i put the wrong "OUTPUT". can you help me again sir? thank you. i updated the question. im really sorry for my mistake